# How to click on a background application while doing other tasks on AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript

Ok so I'm trying make an applescript that clicks on a set spot every set amount of time. The problem is I can't figure out how use the script in the background without it interfering with other applications. I cannot GUI script it as the application I'm scripting for is in Java.

Comment: I suspect your approach is doomed to failure :-( Think about why you need to click on that spot and find a different way of doing it - does refresh a page, or download a file, or what?

Comment: I am using this script to click on a spot in a Java game.

Answer (score 0):

Applescript will not do this very well, but it can be done using other languages fired from the Applescript, like Python:

```
set x to 30
set y to 5
set l to 50 -- click same location 50 times

do shell script "
/usr/bin/python <<END
import sys
import time
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import *
def mouseEvent(type, posx, posy):
theEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(None, type, (posx,posy), kCGMouseButtonLeft)
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent)
def mousemove(posx,posy):
mouseEvent(kCGEventMouseMoved, posx,posy);
def mouseclick(posx,posy):
mouseEvent(kCGEventLeftMouseDown, posx,posy);
mouseEvent(kCGEventLeftMouseUp, posx,posy);
ourEvent = CGEventCreate(None);
currentpos=CGEventGetLocation(ourEvent);             # Save current mouse position
for x in range(0, " & l & "):
          mouseclick(" & x & "," & y & ");
mousemove(int(currentpos.x),int(currentpos.y));      # Restore mouse position
END"
```

[More info here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3708948)